# Retry task without increment retry counter

Tags: celery

Is it possible to retry tasks without increment a retry counter?

My task calling some http backend, and if it is down for some reason, I do not want to  lose my tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `max_retries = None` and it will never stop retrying. Pass it as a keyword to the task decorator or to the retry call itself.

[Documentation](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html)